# Sesame - error initializing repository AbstractParserQuery not found

Tags: java, sesame

I need to implement a simple java application to execute some queries on Seasame. I wanted to try something simple for the beginning but I am not able to initialise the repository. I was following the official guide and my program looks like this:

```
   public class HelloSesame {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dataDir = new File("../../resources/test.ttl");
        Repository rep = new SailRepository(new NativeStore(dataDir));
        rep.initialize();    

        RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection();
        //...omitted code
        }
       }
```

and my pom.xml

```
     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <resources>
         <resource>
           <directory>src</directory>
          <excludes>
         <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
     </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
        <artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>    </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
    <artifactId>sesame-model</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>
 </dependency>    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
   <artifactId>sesame-repository-sail</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>    </dependency>    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
   <artifactId>sesame-queryparser-sparql</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>    </dependency>    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
   <artifactId>sesame-rio-api</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>    </dependency>    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
   <artifactId>sesame-query</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </project>`
```

Every time I try to run this application I get the error:

> 16:02:06.436 [main] DEBUG o.openrdf.sail.nativerdf.NativeStore -
>   Initializing NativeStore... 16:02:06.461 [main] DEBUG
>   o.openrdf.sail.nativerdf.NativeStore - Data dir is
>   ../../resources/test.ttl 16:02:06.540 [main] DEBUG
>   o.openrdf.sail.nativerdf.NativeStore - NativeStore initialized
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openrdf/query/impl/AbstractParserQuery    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ...
>   **at main.jridrer.functiontest.HelloSesame.main(HelloSesame.java:36)** Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   **org.openrdf.query.impl.AbstractParserQuery**    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 15 more

The error is thrown on rep.getConnection() method.
I have tried to search on google but nothing... I have tried to search the class in the org.openrdf.query.impl package bat this class doesn’t exist there...
I have tried to make MemoryStore in place of NativeStore but I get the same error. Does anyone have any idea what i can try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing two different versions of Sesame, which is likely causing the problem. For your dependency on `sesame-runtime` you have 4.0.1, for the other libraries you have 4.1.0. In any case if you are importing specific sesame libraries (such as model, sail-nativerdf, etc), you really don't need the sesame-runtime dependency (which is a 'catch-all' dependency).

You might want to think about using Sesame's Bill Of Materials (BOM) - this makes it a little easier to juggle things as you only define the version of Sesame in one place. See the [documentation](http://rdf4j.org/doc/programming#maven) for more details about this.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the problem, shame on me... I have checked all the versions but I didn’t spot the difference between 4.0.1 and 4.1.0 :/ Thank you!